# Updating a MS Access Table Transposing Structure and Updating Fields

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao

I routinely work with text files that I import into MS Access, and I am trying to extract data from that file to update an existing table.

**The Text File:**
This file has student results from exams, and it comes to me poorly formatted (out of my control) and the number of columns (test questions) vary. I've managed to use other code to clean the file so that it ends up in a table called ETR so that every response to a test question is prefixed with ESid_ followed by an ID number, and the corresponding score is prefixed with points. So a row in the ETR table looks like this (SID is the student ID):

```
SID  ESid_123  points_123  ESid_124  points_124 ...
A1   C           1         A           2
A2   D           0         B           1
```

**The Target Table:**
I'm trying to use those data to update a table called IS_items, which has this structure:

```
IS_itemsID     Administration_ID  SID  ItemID    Choice   Correct   Points
(autonumber)   (user input)       A1  ESid_123  C        1         1
                                  A1  ESid_124  A        1         2
                                  A2  ESid_123  D        0         0
                                  A2  ESiD_124  B        1         1
```

The administration_ID is generated from user input on a form, and the SID is stored in another table. This is my code so far:

```
AdminID = Me.Administration_ID
Dim rsA As dao.Recordset
Dim rsB As dao.Recordset
Dim fld As dao.Field

Set rsA = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ETR", dbOpenDynaset)
Set rsB = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("IS_Items", dbOpenDynaset)

Do Until rsA.EOF
For Each fld In rsA.Fields
    If fld.Name Like "points*" Then
        rsB.AddNew
        rsB!Administration_ID = AdminID
            Filter01 = Chr(34) & rsA!StudentID & Chr(34)
        rsB!SID = DLookup("Students_Tbl_ID", "Students(Main)", "[Student 
Identification Number] = " & Filter01)
        rsB!ItemID = fld.Name
        rsB!Points = fld.Value
        rsB.Update
    End If
Next
rsA.MoveNext
Loop

rsA.Close
rsB.Close

Set rsA = Nothing
Set rsB = Nothing
```

This updates IS_Items correctly for SID, ItemID, and Points but obviously is missing the fields for Choice and Correct. I really need to update the Choice field in IS_Items, but I'd also like to know how to update Correct (the logic would follow that if Points > 0 then Correct = 1 and I realize this is redundant).

Thanks in advance for any guidance---I know this is a big ask, but I'm completely stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider iterating by field index with a `Step` since every 3, 5, 7, ... will be *points* fields. Then look back one for *ItemID*, *Choice*, and *Correct* values. Do note: field indices start at 0 and not 1.

```
For i = 3 To rsA.Fields.Count Step 2

    rsB.AddNew

    rsB!Administration_ID = AdminID
    rsB!SID = DLookup("Students_Tbl_ID", "Students(Main)", "[Student Identification Number] = '" & rsA!StudentID & "'")
    rsB!ItemID = rsA.Fields(i-2).Name
    rsB!Choice = rsA.Fields(i-2).Value
    If rsA.Fields(i-1).Value > 1 Then
        rsB!Correct = 1
    Else
        rsB!Correct = 0
    End If
    rsB!Points = rsA.Fields(i-1).Value

    rsB.Update

Next i
```

Comment: Yes, that works! Thank you very much. I have never seen Step before, and if anyone can provide a link to where I can learn more about it I'd also appreciate that help.

Comment: Great! Glad it works. See MS documentation on the [For ... Next statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement)